# Display a C++ class member in LLDB type summary

Tags: c++, xcode, lldb

I have a C++ class with a `static` member, meaning a class member. I want to display the value of that class member using a custom LLDB type summary, to ease debugging with Xcode. Taking a very simple class for demonstration:

```
class A
{
public:
    int memberValue;
    static int classValue;
};
int A::classValue;

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.memberValue = 8;
    a.classValue = 42;
    return 0;
}
```

Placing a breakpoint on the `return` statement, running the example, I get the following result in the LLDB command window:

```
(lldb) print a
(A) $0 = (memberValue = 8)
(lldb) print a.memberValue
(int) $1 = 8
(lldb) print a.classValue
(int) $2 = 42
(lldb) type summary add -s "${var.memberValue}" A
(lldb) print a
(A) $3 = 8
(lldb) type summary add -s "${var.classValue}" A
(lldb) print a
(A) $4 = error: summary string parsing error
(lldb)
```

The syntax `${var.classValue}` does not work for class members in type summaries as it does for regular members, although LLDB is able to display the value with a `print` command.

I tried with a Python summary provider with no more success: `GetChildMemberWithName` seem to be unable to fetch the class member neither.

Is there any way to display a class member value in a custom LLDB type summary, being through Python or directly?

Comment: According to http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html , (lldb) target variable shows the global and static variables in the file. Maybe this helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don is right, lldb considers static members of a class to be static variables, not children of a class object.

The simple string format for summaries doesn't have syntax for "Global Variable Named ", so you won't be able to add it that way.  So you will have to write a Python based summary.

If you do that, it should be straight-forward to get to a class static.  You were almost there, you just needed to fetch the variable as a static variable not as a child of the object.  Your Python summary gets passed in the SBValue for the object, and you can use `SBValue.GetTarget()` to get the target owning that value, and then you can use `SBTarget.FindFirstGlobalVariable` to find the value of the class static.  In your case, the name of the variable would be `A::classValue`.

Comment: Very good clue. This does not solve my problem completely because in fact my class is a `template` one to support units, and the static member (the unit SI name like "m/s") is different for each `template` instantiation. I will look how to obtain the complete class name of the object.

Comment: Your python summary gets an SBValue representing the value to be summarized.  SBValue has a GetTypeName, but you might want to get the type with GetType instead and if it is a pointer/reference and get the pointee type and then get it's name.  Stripping those characters out of the typename by hand is error prone.